# scripts tab or scripts panel are not showing in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I open Google Chrome's developer tools, I do not get the scripts tab. I have done this on two computers, one running Windows 7 and the other Windows Server 2008 R2. Can you please tell me what I need to do to get the Scripts tab back. Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screenshot of what you are seeing? Scripts are under 'Sources' now

Comment: Thanks! scratching my head :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no scripts tab in the Chrome debugger any more.  You can view the javascript under the Resources tab (though I don't find it all that useful in the Resources tab).

You can view and set breakpoints in your scripts under the Sources tab.  Go to the Sources tab now, click on the right facing arrow at upper left (right below Elements) and then find the script you are looking for.  Click on it there and it will create a tab with just that script in it.  You can then set a breakpoint.